# A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property in loginController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, random

I am a beginner in c# MVC and I write a class `randomGenarator` to generate random number

```
public class RandomGenarator
{

    public int rand()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int  i = rnd.Next(100);
        return i;
    }
}
```

but when I tried to use that in My Controller class

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{ 
    RandomGenarator rnd = new RandomGenarator();
    int i = rnd.rand();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        return View();
    }
 }
```

I am faced with this Error:

> "A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property"

Comment: Initialize the field `i` inside your constructor. `public LoginController() { i = rnd.rand(); }`

Comment: It should also be noted that you shouldn't create a `new Random()` object every time you need a random number to avoid repeated numbers. Create one such object, keep it in memory, and then use it every time to do `.Next(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

That' cause you are not trying to call the method `int i = rnd.rand();` inside a method (OR) constructor in your controller.

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{ 
    private RandomGenarator rnd = null;

    public LoginController()
    {
       rnd = new RandomGenarator();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
     int i = rnd.rand();
     return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i use generate a random number , save that in a integer and use in different Actions. for example, in your code i can not use i in another ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code inside `public ActionResult Index()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i use generate a random number , save that in a integer and use in different Actions. for example, in your code i can not use i in another ActionResult.

Answer (score 0):

The error has the clues, since you are learning, let's break it down.

```
A field initializer
```

The field is int i. Its a field in the class, not a property because there is no getter or setter.

```
cannot reference
```

You cannot use = on this field

```
the nonstatic
```

The other side of the equals, the referenced target, is not static. If it where static then?

```
field, method, or property
```

This is the target i 'referenced' which is the method rand() on the nonstatic object rnd.

So the error is saying you cannot set i to something that is not static.